# Quickfixj bypassing config file and doing it programmatically

Tags: java, quickfix, quickfixj

Hi guys I am following a tutorial on quickfixj to bypass the config file. basically I don't want to have a txt config file, I want to create my own settings before connecting to FIX, the reason that I am doing this is that I want the user to enter his `SendcompID`, `TargetCompID`, Host address and Port address on the GUI before sending the logon.

I have followed this [tutorial](http://quickfix-j.364392.n2.nabble.com/bypassing-config-file-and-doing-it-programmatically-td3283590.html#a7579943)

here is my code

```
  SessionSettings settings = new SessionSettings();

        SessionID id1 = new SessionID(new BeginString("FIX.4.4"), new SenderCompID("ManiFX"), new TargetCompID("ALPHA-FIX"), "Session1");
        Dictionary d = new Dictionary();

        d.setString("ConnectionType", "acceptor");
        d.setString("SocketConnectPort", "7403");
        d.setString("SocketConnectHost", "185.79.219.199");
        d.setString("FileLogPath", "C:/Work/QuickFIXJ/logs");
       // d.setString("StartDay", "sunday");
        //d.setString("EndDay", "saturday");
        d.setString("StartTime", "00:00:00");
        d.setString("EndTime", "00:00:00");
        d.setString("FileStorePath", "/Users/renan.gado/workspace/QuickFix/src/Sessioninfo");
        d.setString("UseDataDictionary", "n");
        d.setString("DataDictionary", "FIX44.xml");

        settings.set(id1,d);

        Application application = new QuickFix();
        FileStoreFactory storeFactory = new FileStoreFactory(settings);
        ScreenLogFactory logFactory = new ScreenLogFactory(settings);
        MessageFactory messageFactory = new DefaultMessageFactory();
        SocketInitiator acceptor = new SocketInitiator(application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory, messageFactory);


        acceptor.start();
```

And I am getting the following error

```
 SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
 SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
 SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further  details.
 Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException:     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
 at  javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
 at  com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventH andler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at  com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManag er.java:191)
at  com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at  com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at  com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at  com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at  com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at  com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at  com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl .java:114)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
  at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
  at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
  at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
  at  com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
 at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
 at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
 at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
 at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
 at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
 ... 48 more
 Caused by: quickfix.ConfigError: no initiators in settings
at quickfix.mina.initiator.AbstractSocketInitiator.createSessions(AbstractSocketInitiator.java:202)
  at quickfix.mina.initiator.AbstractSocketInitiator.createSessionInitiators(AbstractSocketInitiator.java:83)
  at quickfix.SocketInitiator.initialize(SocketInitiator.java:114)
  at quickfix.SocketInitiator.start(SocketInitiator.java:89)
  at controller.Controller.connectButtonAction(Controller.java:174)
     ... 58 more
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Thank you.

also if there is a better way to achieve what I am trying to accomplish please share your ideas.

Comment: Any good reasons why you want to hard code config in the code ? Every time you need to change a config, have to get your code recompiled, which is wrong on so many levels. Supposedly you need to connect to 1000 counterparties, why do you want to increase your troubles ?

Comment: I will be only connecting to 1 counterparty at time, I want want to hardcode the config so i can pass the parameters that i want to connect everytime. for example: host address, port, target comp id, sender comp id, and fix version. if there is a better way to do that using a txt config please let me know

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use the Quickfix config files which quickfix reads by default ?

Comment: So to be honest, Im new to quickfix, so i want to be able to set  host address, port, target comp id, sender comp id, and fix version. can i pass those values from code when using config file? if yes do you know how its done. the reason that I am trying to implement it in code rather than using the config file is that I think this is the only way i can specify the parameters that i want to send whenever im going to create a connection

Comment: Go through the documentation here http://www.quickfixj.org/documentation/ . And then try debugging.

Comment: use the default config file like @DumbCoder says :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get it working purely programmatically, but the first workaround that springs to mind is write code that generates a QuickFix config file and point your various objects at that file in the usual manner.

The code that writes the file is pretty simple, right - either use a simple template and substitute in what you want to change, or have a series of printlns that generate all of the file in code.

Comment: I will do that, Thank you